# Does the line on a zener diode correspond with the line in the symbol?

Tags: diodes, components, zener, symbol

For a *normal* diode, the thin line on the component corresponds with the line of the symbol. Is this the same for a *zener* diode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's the cathode. Don't take my word for it, it's easily tested with a multimeter; the voltage drop with this line negative should be 0.6V or so, the same as any other Si diode. To see the zener voltage, connect it reverse biassed (thin line positive)